# power apps find the contain [value] in SQL column field and get last 3 digit to plus 1 and autonumbering

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

[image]

IN SQL table [SOP10100] - it have different type running SOPNUMBE,

I wish to add the **numbering +1**

**First Record = MBO0000003**

**Next Record  = MBO0000004**

Now I only able to get last value with MBO0000002 with the below script.

```
Last(Filter(SOP10100,StartsWith(SOPNUMBE,"MBO"))).SOPNUMBE
```

= **MBO0000002**

May I know how add the number + 1?

Below when I write script it return me empty value

```
Right(Last(Filter(SOP10100,StartsWith(SOPNUMBE,"MBO"))).SOPNUMBE,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

your field `SOPNUMBE` field is not consistent, it has MBO0000003 and also OSRW0000004
I tried to do something with your SOPNUMBE

```
Right(Last(SOPNUMBECollection).SOPNUMBE,4)
```

It gave me 0002 and then I checked if it is numeric or not

```
IsNumeric(Right(Last(SOPNUMBECollection).SOPNUMBE,4))
```

If it returns true that means I can add one number to it. This works for me.

Note `SOPNUMBECollection` is a local colleciton I created.

Field `SOPNUMBE` is Text field in my case, I think that is the same for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Text(
                    Value(Right(Trim(Last(Filter(SOP10100,StartsWith(SOPNUMBE,"MBO"))).SOPNUMBE),3))+1
                    ,"MBO0000000"
      )
```

I finally found the answer myself.

[image]